# Limit of $n^{k/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to find the radius of convergence for $\sum n^k z^n$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Using the root test, I want to find
 $$lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \; n^{k/n}$$

I know $lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \; n^{1/n} = 1$, so  using properties of convergent sequences, $lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \; n^{k/n} = 1^k = 1 $.

---

First, is this right/Is there a better way to prove this?

Second, this makes no intuitive sense, shouldn't this sequence diverge since $n^{k/n} \geq n^{1/n}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. And, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1$, the fact that you always have $n^{k/n}\geqslant n^{1/n}$ does not imply at all that $(n^{k/n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ diverges.